# How to get list of filenames from directory with same extension using python?

Tags: python, cmd

i want to make a list of filenames or filepathes with same extension that i set. For example, I have a directory C:\data with many files in it. I set extension parameter (for example .txt). What i need is to create a list of filepathes to those files, like this:

```
['C:\\data\\example1.txt','C:\\data\\example2.txt','C:\\data\\example3.txt']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all files of a directory in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `glob` module:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('C:\\data\\*.txt')
['C:\\data\\1.txt', 'C:\\data\\card.txt']
```

For more information, see the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed!